# Adjusting for non-confounders based on DAG

Tags: regression, estimation, inference, causality, dag

I've drawn the following DAG to represent my data generating process
[image]

I'm interested in estimating the effects of `G1` and `G3` on `OS` via a linear model. It's my understanding that assuming the DAG is correct, I can estimate the effect of `G1` by conditioning on G1 alone because it's directly related to `OS`. To estimate `G3`, I should avoid conditioning on `G2` because it's a mediator. I could use the following model forms:

$$Y = \beta_{G1}X_{G1}$$

$$Y = \beta_{G3}X_{G3}$$

My question regards conditioning on the other, non-mediator variables that affect `OS`. Should I include `Smoking`, `Stage`, `Gender`, `Age`, and `Radiation` in the models? They don't seem to meet the definition of confounder from [this post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/445578/how-do-dags-help-to-reduce-bias-in-causal-inference), but I wasn't sure if including these variables could yield more accurate estimates (assuming I have sufficient samples).

Should non-confounders that still affect the outcome be included in regression models to increase precision?

Comment: Yes, the precision of the estimate depends on the residual variance, so minimizing it by increasing the variance explained in your model improves precision.

Comment: Are there any common scenarios when you wouldn't include these other variables?

Comment: If you're DAG is wrong and the variables are actually mediators or colliders, they should not be included. Therefore, don't include those that could even possibly be affected by G1 or G3. Including very weak predictors of the outcome might slightly reduce precision, but with a large sample, this is unlikely to affect it. If the model is nonlinear (e.g., logistic), including those covariates changes the estimand, bot with linear models.