# How to build a GLMM that observes the years since experimental design was established?

Tags: time-series, experiment-design, glmm, nested-data, crossed-random-effects

**Hello,** my first question, quite individual, so I find it difficult to relate already answered questions to mine.

I have observed the vegetation development in forests of 5 different areas (`area`) in an experimental experiment. The design can be classified according to 3 types of size and distribution (`treatment`) including control plot, and the occurrence of `deadwood` with 5 types including control plot. For each treatment there is every option of deadwood and vice versa. The data have been collected for 4 years (`years` -> 1y-4y). Five microclimate variables (`mc1-5`) are included as fixed effects. As random effects I would like to include `area`, `treatment` and `deadwood`.
With regard to vegetation development it is interesting how the effects of microclimate (`mc1-5`), but especially of `treatment` and `deadwood` have changed over the `years`. In `area` the factor `years` should be negligible.
As I understand it, `years` and `treatment` /`deadwood` are nested, because the same plots are examined every year.

My previous attempt to build a model:

```
glmm <- glmer(species.number ~ mc1 + mc2 + mc3 + mc4 + mc5 + 
              (1|treatment/years) + (1|deadwood/years) + (1|area), 
              data=df, family = poisson)
```

Among other things, I am confused by [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/228814) actually very good answer that in my case it might be crossed data after all?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: (+1) Can you provide more details please - how many areas and treatments are there ? Is deadwood binary? It sounds like your research question concerns the effect of the mc variables on the number of species, but also how these evolve over time - is that correct ? If not please explain your research question. I am sorry that my answer you linked to has confused you !!

Comment: First of all, the confusion is due to my dilettantism in r and GLMM in particular, definitely not due to your answer. I have edited some information in the question above, I hope it helps. Your assumption regarding the research question is correct!

Comment: Thanks for the info. Can you explain with a bit more detail what the variables `treatment` and `deadwood` actually are ?

Comment: They are both kind of grouping variables. `treatment` describes the size and distribution of disturbances in forest in one letter: A = aggregated, C = control, D = distributed. `deadwood` describes the occurrence of deadwood in the same way, lying deadwood, standing deadwood, standing + lying, control, removed...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The central interest is in the "effects" of the microclimate variables, and whether these change over time. As such, time should be treated as a fixed effect. Treating it as random will only allow for counts to be more similar in one year than another. Interacting `year` with the microclimate variables will help to answer the research questions.

`area` seems to meet the usual criteria for treating a factor as random - samples from a greater population of areas, with no actual interest in the "effects" of the different areas, with the exception of the number of areas. 5 is on the cusp of what is generally thought of as the minimum number of levels for treating a factor as random in the frequentist paradigm. It could be argued either way whether it should be random or not.

From the description in the comments, `treatment` and `deadwood` appear to be factors that are crossed, but each  nested within `area`. They don't really seem like samples from a wider population, however this is not crucial as there are often conflicting criteria (and other criteria I haven't mentioned). Since they are nested within area, we don't need to worry about them having only 3 and 5 levels.

So the model I would suggest is:

```
species.number ~ mc1*year + mc2*year + mc3*year + mc4*year + mc5*year + (1|area) + (1|area:treatment) + (1|area:deadwood)
```

If you expect a linear association of the counts with time, then it would be a good idea to treat `year` as numeric (0,1,2,3), particularly if the microclimate variables are categorical, otherwise you will have a lot of output to interpret.

Lastly I would also suggest some consideration about whether there is an causual dependence among any of the fixed or random effects - are all the microclimate variables independent from each other and the the treatment and deadwood variables.

Comment: Thanks so much! For further explanation: Each `area` has the same 9 plots. These 9 plots are each divided into a `treatment` A = aggregated and D = distributed, which have 4 different `deadwood` categories each, plus a C = control plot that remains untouched (in case of `treatment` AND of `deadwood`). The microclimate variables are partly related to each other (for example light intensity and temperature) as well as to the respective `treatment` and `deadwood`. I think this complicates things even more ;)

Comment: The central question is how vegetation changes over time, with special regards to `treatment` / `deadwood` and the resulting microclimate. Furthermore: the effects of `treatment` and `deadwood` also change slightly over time.

Comment: Not to worry :) The main thing to avoid is interpreting the main effects if any of the others are mediator. Mediators should be excluded and you will need to fit a seperate model to assess the impact of the mediators seperatley.  Check my answer [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/445578/how-do-dags-help-to-reduce-bias-in-causal-inference) for details of how to proceed with that.

Comment: Hmm, regarding your 2nd comment, this is making me think that `treatment` and  `deadwood` should be fixed effects,.