# Apparent anomaly in coefficients in multinomial logistic regression

Tags: multinomial-logit

I am seeing some results that point to a clear conceptual gap in my understanding of multinomial logistic regression and am seeking an explanation.

I am performing multinomial logistic regression on a dataset in which the dependent variable has three levels. I first cross-tabulated the relationship between the dependent variable y (with levels y1, y2 and y3) and one categorical independent variable x (with levels x1 and x2). The cross-table of x and y showing row-wise percentages looks like this:

```
                  y
         --------------------
         |   y1    y2    y3
  |--------------------------
  |  x1  |  47.6   28.4. 23.9
x |  x2  |  26.1   21.4. 52.5
```

From the above table, it is clear that the probability of y3 is much higher when x = x2 than when x = x1. Also, the odds of y3 relative to y1 are also much higher when x = x2 than when x = x1.

I then ran a multinomial logistic regression with **several independent variables in addition to x**, with y = y1 and x = x1 as the reference values. I got the following coefficients for x from the regression:

```
====================================================
                  Dependent variable:     
                  ----------------------------
                    y2        y3        
----------------------------------------------------
x_x2              1.079***    -0.484***  
----------------------------------------------------
```

From the coefficients, I can see that the log odds of y3 relative to y1 will **decrease** by 0.484 when x changes from x1 to x2. This seems like an anomaly given how the odds of y3 relative to y1 in the cross-table above are much higher for x = x2 than for x = x1. Of course, I understand that in the regression, I am using many other independent variables and that these could have an impact, but am unable to see how such an impact might come about.

I would appreciate if someone can throw more light on how the presence of other independent variables can cause something like this to happen.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This can happen when you condition on a mediator.

It is not specific to multinomial regression, or categorical data.

A simple simulation can demonstrate this:

```r
set.seed(1)
N <- 100

X <- rnorm(N)
M <- -2*X + rnorm(N)   # mediator
Y <- X + M + rnorm(N)
```

Now we fit a model, with `X` as the only predictor:

```r
> summary(lm(Y ~ X))

Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept) -0.01032    0.13915  -0.074    0.941    
X           -0.97989    0.15456  -6.340 7.07e-09 ***
```

And now we also condition on M:

```r
> summary(lm(Y ~ X + M))

Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)  0.02535    0.10519   0.241  0.81005    
X            0.91418    0.24824   3.683  0.00038 ***
M            0.94653    0.10948   8.646 1.12e-13 ***
```

and now we find that the sign of the estimate for `X` has reversed, which is equivalent to what you have found in your data. This happens because when you condition on a mediator, it blocks the otherwise open backdoor path between `Y` and `X`, and therefore only estimates the direct effect of `X` (which is positive), whereas, without conditioning on `M`, the backdoor path is open, so the model estimates the total effect of `X` on `Y` which is negative. More detail about this can be found here:
[How do DAGs help to reduce bias in causal inference?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/445578/how-do-dags-help-to-reduce-bias-in-causal-inference/445606#445606)

If you want to see this with multinomial `Y` and binary `X`, then you can easily adapt the above code to discretise the data.

Comment: I found your clear explanation to be very helpful. Thanks!

Comment: @ViswaV you are very welcome. Thanks for the feedback :)  If this answers your question, please consider marking it as the accepted answer (just click the tick mark)