# Multiple linear regresion in R

Tags: r, multiple-regression, regression-coefficients

I am creating a multiple linear regression model $M_1$ with `aggression` as response and `parenting_style` and `sibling_aggression` as explanatory variables using the **child_aggression** data.

Below is my code:

```
m1 <- linear_reg() %>%
  set_engine("lm") %>%
  fit(aggression ~ parenting_style + sibling_aggression, data = cha) 
m1 %>% tidy()
```

The output:

```
# A tibble: 3 x 5
  term               estimate std.error statistic     p.value
  <chr>                 <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>       <dbl>
1 (Intercept)        -0.00578    0.0121    -0.479 0.632      
2 parenting_style     0.0620     0.0123     5.06  0.000000551
3 sibling_aggression  0.0934     0.0375     2.49  0.0130
```

how can I interpret each of the 3 model coefficients in simple terms?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would interpret these results as:

- every 1 unit increase in `parenting_style` is associated with a 0.06 increase in `aggression`
- every 1 unit increase in `sibling_aggression` is associated with a 0.09 increase in `aggression`
- the p-values indicate that if these associations were actually absent, the probability of observing these data (or data even more extreme) is very low.

I would also like to make a few points about this model which will hopefully be useful. First, I assume you have thought about the causal relations between these variables. When dealing with causal inference it is important to decide which variable is the main exposure, for which you want to estimate the total causal effect. Is it possible that `sibling_aggression` has a causal effect on `parenting_style`? If so then you need to remove `parenting_style` from the model because it is a mediator. If not, perhaps it is a confounder ? If so then you should retain it. Second, do you expect the associations between these variables to be linear ? Linearity is often plausible over a small range, but over a bigger range sometimes you need to allow for non-linear associations, include interactions ? For instance, perhaps the "effect" of parenting style is different depending on the level of `sibling_aggression`. If so, then you would want to consider the interaction between these variables. Or, perhaps the direct associations are quadratic, logarithmic or some other non-linear relationships. If so then you can can transform the variables or introduce non-linear terms to the model. Third, what scale are the variables on ? Typically in my experience these kinds of data are often ordinal, rather than continuous ? If so, then this should also be taken into account.

Simple models are good. As Einstein, once said "Everything should be made as simple as possible, but not simpler". However it is important to consider that a model may be too simplistic to be useful.

If you would like to know more about how to estimate causal effects while minimising any biases, please refer to this question and answer:

[How do DAGs help to reduce bias in causal inference?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/445578/how-do-dags-help-to-reduce-bias-in-causal-inference/)

I hope that at least some of this helps !

Comment: Just one small question does the intercept really carry any meaning while interpreting the coefficient terms or just because it is a constant term we do not consider it? Apart from that, this a very excellent answer. And thanks for the redirection for the causal effect. Cheers!

Comment: You're very welcome. The intercept is interpreted as the expected value of `aggression` when `parenting_style` and `sibling_aggression` are BOTH ZERO. So a lot will depend on the scales of your variables and whether a value of zero for them makes sense. This is one reason why, when dealing with continuous variables, it can be a good idea to centre them about their mean; this way, the interpretation refers to the mean of a particular variable, rather than it being zero which often makes no sense (eg. weight of a person is never zero)

Comment: Just to summarize if I understood your comment on `intercept` whether it is positive or negative we should not try attributing any meaning to it. Is that right?

Comment: It depends on the context and in particular on the scale(s) of the variables. If it doesn't make sense for the variables to be zero, then you might consider centereing them about their mean. Then the intercept takes on the interpretation of the value of the responses when the covariates are at their means.

Comment: It is more clear now! Thank you for the pointers!