# Do confounder variables need to have a causal effect on treatment AND response variables?

Tags: experiment-design, causality, confounding

Let's look at an example:

> We want to know if our new jogging shirt reduces the amount of sweat produced by runners. Ten factory employees in Bangkok, Thailand are recruited to try out the prototype by jogging for 30 minutes and recording the amount of sweat on their foreheads. Ten office employees from Vancouver, Canada are recruited to do the same thing wearing the old jogging shirt.

Our predictor is the jogging shirt and the response is sweat amounts. Could a confounder be the weather since higher temperatures will cause someone to sweat more? This doesn't affect the predictor since the people in the study are forced to wear a new or old shirt. **Is weather a confounder even though it doesn't have a causal effect on the predictor? How could I adjust the experiment to account for the confounder?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Weather certainly affects amount of sweat, and it would be wise to include it in your analysis! A [confounding variable is a variable that sets up a backdoor path](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/445578/how-do-dags-help-to-reduce-bias-in-causal-inference). Since weather does not set up a backdoor path (because it's not connected to the treatment at all), it is not technically a confounder. However, from the perspective of the design of experiments, it seems clear to me that weather should be a blocking factor. That is, in a linear regression setting, you would include weather on the RHS of the model. Not doing so would introduce much more variation than you probably want.

Comment: What would be a *confounder* in this case?

Comment: The only possible confounders would have to be variables that affected how the treatment was assigned. If the treatment is truly random, there can be no true confounders: that's the whole idea of an experiment, and why experiments have, for so long, been considered good ways of getting at causality (via Mill's Methods).

Comment: Which variables affected how the treatment was assigned in this case?

Comment: And by block, do you mean we should randomly assign 5 of the people from each location to the new/old jogging shirts? Thank you so much

Comment: Yes, the indicated design is not proper. It is as you say: for blocking, we should do this: for each location, five people should be randomly assigned to the new shirt, and five to the old. In this scenario, there was no variable affecting how the treatment was assigned. But you could dream up scenarios where the assignment was based on something.